Systemd unit file with multiple instance parameters (including user)
If a systemd unit file has a prefix (i.e. without the .service, .timer etc. suffix) followed by @, then the unit can be instantiated – that is, I can enable or start the unit multiple times, each time with a different parameter. Inside the unit file, wherever %i or %I occurs, it will be replaced with the parameter (%i is escaped while %I is not).
For example, ifup@.service controls network interfaces. In order to bring up, say, eth0, I would run sudo systemctl start ifup@eth0.service.
Now suppose I want to write a unit which launches a specific process as a specific user. I want the user account to be instantiable, and also pass an instance-specific argument to the process. That would imply two parameters, one for the user and one for the command line argument. However, I see no indication in the documentation of this being supported.
Is there a way to pass multiple arguments to a systemd unit instance? If so, how? (And will this also work in User=?)
Currently I see two workarounds:
Workaround 1: User name equals command line argument
Create a unit file named foo@.service with the following entries in [Service]:
User=%I
ExecStart=/path/to/exec --somearg %i

Pros:

Works for any user account

Cons:

The command line argument must contain the user name. While this can usually be achieved if the argument is a config file, there are also use cases for which this won’t work.
Each user is restricted to one single set of arguments. If there is a need for two instances with the same user name but a different command line, separate unit files are needed.
If the arg is a config file and is expected to reside somewhere underneath the user’s home dir, its name could just as well be static – no benefit in using variables.

Workaround 2: Use %j/%J as second parameter
If a systemd unit file contains %j/%J as placeholders, they will be replaced with the part of the prefix that follows the last hyphen (or the entire prefix if it contains no hyphen). %j is escaped, %J is not.
Create a unit file named foo-USER@.service, once for each user the unit will be used with (replacing USER with the actual user name), and the following entries in [Service]:
User=%J
ExecStart=/path/to/exec --somearg %i

Of course, the inverse is also possible: The unit file would be named foo-ARG@.service and have the following entries in [Service]:
User=%I
ExecStart=/path/to/exec --somearg %j

Pros:

User and command line arg are not linked to each other, allowing for multiple instances with the same user but a different command line

Cons:

The value to be passed as %j/%J (either the user name or the command line arg) cannot contain a hyphen, else it will get truncated to the part after the last hyphen. This may lead to behavior that is undesirable, possibly even in a security-relevant way (e.g. the unit running as user bowles instead of parker-bowles).
One copy of the unit file is still needed for every possible value of %j/%J – either for each user or for each possible command line argument. Still, a benefit is that files can be copied/renamed without changing their contents. Unless systemd is picky about symlinks (which I haven’t tested), these files could even be just symlinks to a template file (which I recommend naming something like foo-@.service). If the use case involves enabling unit instances prior to using them, having to create symlinks for each instance before enabling it would be a relatively minor extra step, not a major drawback.


A systemd template service only accepts a single parameter. From the systemd.unit man page:

Unit names can be parameterized by a single argument called the "instance name". The unit is then constructed based on a "template file" which serves as the definition of multiple services or other units. A template unit must have a single "@" at the end of the unit name prefix (right before the type suffix). The name of the full unit is formed by inserting the instance name between "@" and the unit type suffix. In the unit file itself, the instance parameter may be referred to using "%i" and other specifiers, see below.

What I generally do for what you're describing is to use the instance name to look up a configuration with the additional parameters. For example, let's say I have a service run-web-server@.service that runs a web server for a user. It needs to know the username, the path to the HTML document root, and a port on which to listen. I might write something like this:
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/run-web-server/%i.env
User=%i
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/darkhttpd $WEB_SERVER_ROOT --port $WEB_SERVER_PORT

If I place in /etc/run-web-server/alice.env the following:
WEB_SERVER_ROOT=/home/alice/mydocs
WEB_SERVER_PORT=8080

Then I can run systemctl start run-web-server@alice.service and this will result in the process /usr/sbin/darkhttpd /home/alice/mydocs --port 8080 running as user alice.

Good explanation and nice extension for the workarounds I’d proposed. Basically it’s a way to maintain config files for executables that don’t support config files. With user=%i you’re still limited to one config per user (Alice can’t run one web server at 8080 and another at 8081), but my Workaround 2 would remove that limitation.
